# Weblogic 12c: SOAPException: Header child element must be namespace qualified

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic12c, saaj

We are migrating a SOAP web service from Weblogic 11g to Weblogic 12c. Clients send a no namespace qualified SOAP header that the web service reads and uses. But when we deploy it to Weblogic 12c we get this Exception:

javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Header child element 'qwe' must be namespace qualified!

jun 17, 2019 3:45:47 P.M. com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.HeaderImpl addHeaderElement
GRAVE: SAAJ0131: HeaderElements debe estar cualificado por espacio de nombres

17/06/2019 15:45:47:801|ERROR|FlowValidationHandler.handleMessage| FlowValidationHandler Exception javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: HeaderElements must be namespace qualified
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: HeaderElements must be namespace qualified
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.SOAPMessageContextImpl.getMessage(SOAPMessageContextImpl.java:87)

We have read that SOAP standard requires header elements to be namespace qualified, but we can’t make changes in clients.

To try to avoid this exception, we have use the approach explained in:

[javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Header child element 'username' must be namespace qualified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929338/javax-xml-soap-soapexception-header-child-element-username-must-be-namespace)

We have included saaj-impl-1.4.0.jar and its dependencies (activation-1.1.jar, javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar, mimepull-1.9.7.jar, stax-api-1.0-2.jar, stax-ex-1.7.8.jar) in WEB-INF/lib and we have added this in weblogic.xml:

```
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>javax.xml.soap.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

But we get this Exception:

) for the method's defining class, javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPMessageContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage used in the signature
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext.getMessage()Ljavax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, es/qwe/handler/FlowValidationHandler, and the class loader (instance of ) for the method's defining class, javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPMessageContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage used in the signature

Any idea?